# Why does this space appear?

Tags: css

These boxes have the same styles but different structures.

http://codepen.io/KevanM/pen/mWeOJV  (code below)

Why does the second row have a space between the boxes, but not on the second - looking in Chrome Tools, there's no space taken up by margin or padding.

```
<div class="switch">
    <p class="english">
        <span class="switch-active">Foo</span>
        <a title="Cymraeg" href="#">
            <span class="cymraeg">Bar</span>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="switch">
    <p class="cymraeg">
        <a title="English" href="#">
            <span class="english">Foo</span>
        </a>
        <span class="switch-active">Bar</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.switch p {
color: #fff;
}

.switch .english span.switch-active {
background-color: #b50038;
}
.switch .english span {
background-color: #bbb;
padding: 10px;
}

.switch .english span {
background-color: #bbb;
padding: 10px;
}

.switch .cymraeg span.switch-active {
background-color: #b50038;
}

.switch .cymraeg span {
background-color: #bbb;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a space before your `span` tag. Remove it and the space will be gone!

```
<div class="switch"><p class="cymraeg"><a title="English" href="#"><span class="english">Foo</span></a>`space comes here`<span class="switch-active">Bar</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because (some of) your elements are `inline-block` display type, they are sensitive to the whitespace in the HTML code. If you remove the white space between the `foo`/`bar` anchor and span elements the space will disappear .

```
 .... active">Foo</span><a title="Cymraeg" href="#"><span ...
                      ^^^^^
                No gap, no space.               

<hr/>

 ...<span class="english">Foo</span></a>  <span class="switch .... 
                                       ^^^^^^
                                  Gap in code, gap in output
```

**Solutions:**
Remove whitespace between HTML elements in your code.

Or, read [a good post by David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block) about how to remove the space in code appearing in HTML/CSS output.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have spaces in between the closure of your  tag and span on the second example:

> `</a>  <span class="switch-active">Bar</span></p>`

remove it:

> `</a><span class="switch-active">Bar</span></p`>

and you should be fine:

```css
.switch .english span.switch-active {
background-color: #b50038;
}
.switch .english span {
background-color: #bbb;
padding: 10px;
}

.switch .english span {
background-color: #bbb;
padding: 10px;
}

.switch .cymraeg span.switch-active {
background-color: #b50038;
}

.switch .cymraeg span {
background-color: #bbb;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch"><p class="english"><span class="switch-active">Foo</span><a title="Cymraeg" href="#"><span class="cymraeg">Bar</span></a></p></div>

<hr/>

<div class="switch"><p class="cymraeg"><a title="English" href="#"><span class="english">Foo</span></a><span class="switch-active">Bar</span></p>
```